# windows universal app passing ref class object to a native c++ thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, win-universal-app, native, c++-cx

I'm trying to use C++ native threads in windows universal app(windows 10) but

```
classname^obj=ref new classname();
std::thread t1(function,obj);//or  thread t1(function,std::ref(obj));//
t1.detach();
--------------------------------
function(classname^x){
//do something on x
}
```

an exception occurs and I get this error : x information not available,

What is the correct form for passing the ref obj into this thread?

Comment: C++/CX references have stack semantics. As soon as `obj` goes out of scope, the ref count goes down. In case the thread function hasn't increased the ref count by that time, the object gets destroyed, leaving the thread with a dangling pointer. You either need to implement synchronization so that you know when the thread is done initializing, or go with something that offers more control over object life times (like WRL).